# How to connect ssh and run shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh

I have a simple app on the server and I want to run it automatically from my computer.
I can connect to server successfully via this script:

```sh
spawn ssh -t login@ip
expect "password"
send "password\r"
interact
```

but I can't change directory to folder with my app. 
I tried so:

```sh
spawn ssh -t login@ip bash -c "cd /var/app"
```

and so:

```sh
spawn ssh -t ssh login@ip 'cd /var/app && exec bash -l'
```

and so:

```sh
spawn ssh -t login@ip
expect "password"
send "password\r"
cd var/app
exec bash
interact
```

**and also other variants...**

but via script it doesn't work because my script want to change directory on my local machine (not at server). 
Can I resolve this problem? 
Thank you for attention.

Comment: Did you try `ssh -t login@ip bash -c 'cd /var/app && bash ./scriptname'`? Why is it crucial to `cd` in the first place instead of just calling `bash /path/to/script`?

Comment: I concur with @dessert: `ssh localhost 'cd /boot/grub && exec /bin/pwd'` works fine and returns `/boot/grub` as expected.

Comment: `ssh user@server 'bash -s' < local_script.sh` or `ssh user@server '/path/to/script'` . In the first you store the script local, in the second on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute multiple commands via `ssh` use a subshell like this:

```
ssh user@host bash -c 'pwd ; dir && ls'
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.